# AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters setVolume: linear or logarithmic?

Tags: ios, slider, avfoundation, volume

From [this](http://www.dr-lex.be/info-stuff/volumecontrols.html) web page:

> ***Volume sliders must not be linear.***

I wanted to know if `AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters setVolume` is linear or logarithmic, couldn't find this on Apple's reference documentation.

If linear, is there an easy solution to convert a percentage to the logarithmic value?